# Is this the shortest javascript regex to find all uppercase consonants?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]/g
```

This is 20 total characters. http://regex101.com/quiz/# quiz #3 says that the shortest solution is 16 characters, but I'm not sure if that is for the JavaScript flavor of regexes.

Comment: Your regex is already 16 characters. the slashes and `g` are not part of it.

Comment: For this particular website they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it a little bit shorter by using a `\P{Lu}` class:

```
[^\P{Lu}AEIOU]
```

[I'm not restricting this to Javascript because regex101 is primarily PCRE flavour]

The above has 14 characters. Since the puzzle also adds in characters from the word boundaries and flags, this adds 3 more characters for `//g`, hence total 17 characters.

In .NET, you can do it shorter:

```
[B-Z-[EIOU]]
```

(12 chars long)

For javascript:

```
(?![EIOU])[B-Z]
```

15 chars excluding delimiters and flag.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not familiar with that notation. Anywhere I can read a little more about it and does Javascript support it?

Comment: @KeithGrout Sorry, JS doesn't support that class. You can read more about them [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties).

Comment: Awesome. Your solution *is* the shortest solution per regex101 (where I mistakenly thought I was using javascript). Gotta accept the other answer since it answers exactly what I asked... No hard feelings eh?

Comment: @KeithGrout Huh didn't think about a shorter regex for JS until now. Edited answer =P

Comment: Thank you, I learned from this answer about `\p` and `\P`. But wait.. why is it the accepted one? `/[^\P{Lu}AEIOU]/g ` are 17 chars, not 16...

Comment: @DannyLo That's just what the OP marked at the time... lautumn added their answer 5 years after the OP asked the question (the shortest I guess at the time of this comment) and OP is probably not around that much anymore to change it.

Answer (score 8):

16 char regex

`(?![AEIOU])[A-Z]`

Comment: hehehe i did the reverse one and got one char more :(

Comment: You know what? we are always positive. Never thought in a negative way . Yeah B-)

Comment: Thanks guys, just learning regexes. Off to study the lookahead which seems pretty helpful.

Comment: You can make it 1 char shorter, count from `B`:  `(?![EIOU])[B-Z]`

Answer (score 7):

this is Only ASCII, so this will the shortest regex, use Negated Character Classes, please see [Negated Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

`[^ -AEIOU[-ÿ]`, 13 characters

`/[^ -AEIOU[-ÿ]/g`, with flag, 16 characters

Comment: Doesn't work anymore `Test 5/10: Your regex is matching characters in the range 0-31, and I'm quite certain those are not consonants!`

Comment: @DannyLo If you can copy "[^-AEIOU[-ÿ]" (show as "[^U+0001-AEIOU[-ÿ]" on regex101.com), copy it, or generate it with bash. I use `echo -en '[^\x01-AEIOU[-ÿ]' | pbcopy ` on macos to copy.

Comment: @liudongmiao ah, so that's not a whitespace... not it makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 3):

My regex is 17 characters in length! I am still one shorter!

```
(?=[A-Z])[^AEIOU]
```

Using lookahead it is first checking the next character is in between `A-Z` or not. Then its checking for a `Non-Vowel` character.

Comment: So, is this similar in execution to an if statement? For example, if(a capital letter){return !CapitalVowel}

Comment: @KeithGrout In this particular case, yes. But its not return, its match.