# After last vowel character, want to attach "xy"

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

My application requirement is if a single word has a vowel like "anupam" then after its last vowel add "xy". So its result should be "anupxy". But if two vowel continue with in a word then it should be like :

```
      Oa = Oaxy
    and au = auxy
Gardenhire = Gardxy

Parker = Parkxy

Arney = Arnxy

There are 4 rules.
1. The name cuts off at the second vowel and is replaced by 'xy.'
2. connected vowels count as a single and should stay together.
3. EXCEPTION: when the last letter is 'x' another 'x' is not added.
4. Names with only two connected vowels should have &quot;xy&quot; added to the end
```

I don't know where is my mistake, My code is :

```
function doit(userName) {
        var temp = userName.toLowerCase();
        var vowels = "aeiouy"
        var count = 0;

        if(userName) {
            for(var i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {

                if( vowels.indexOf(temp.charAt(i)) > -1 ) {
                    count++;
                    if(count==1) {
                        while( vowels.indexOf(temp.charAt(++i)) != -1 );
                        i--;
                    } else
                        break;
                }
            }

            userName = userName.substr(0, i);
            if( userName.charAt(userName.length-1) == 's' )
                userName += "y";
            else
                userName += "sy";
        } else
            userName = 'Take a lap, Dummy';
        return userName.toUpperCase();

    }
```

Comment: don't use break. break is for switch statement

Comment: @C-link no.. [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) is a flow control statement...

Comment: @ArunPJohny there no label and switch statements, is that okay with break?

Comment: @C-link: Yes, that is perfectly compatible with break. The `break` in the OP serves to exit the `for` loop prematurely (when `count` != `1`).

Comment: @ArunPJohny Also, the OP is using medial braces for if else condition and sometimes not, is that manner right? I think there is a problem with that the last else condition.

Comment: requirement change little bit pls help its urgent... i update question

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression is the way to go.

```
var word = "anumap";
var transformed = word.replace(/(\w+[aeiou]+).*/i, " $1xy");
```

I've created an interactive fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/53qH6

The "\w+" means match any word character. This will get all letters before the last vowel.
The [] and vowels in them are what we are looking for and the + outside of the brackets means that there must be at least one vowel.
The ".*" means match anything that comes next (anything after the last vowel)
The parenthesis means capture it into a variable ($1).

Comment: +1.  Nice regex, but in practice regex may be a bad choice as it's hard to read and maintain.  This is an example where a comment indicating the purpose and logic of the regex absolutely must accompany the code.

Comment: You're right @ZacharyBurt, I am writing on an ipad which has proven to be a terrible idea, so I got lazy.  I added an explanation. If anything doesn't make sense please ask.  I would argue however that this relatively simple regex is much easier to read and maintain than the doit() function above ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a regular expression, particularly when using an interpreted language. Much simpler code, and likely much better performance as well. See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
function doit(userName) {
    var str = userName || "";
    var vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
    var suffix = "xy";

    var str_arr = str.split("");
    var str_arr_rev = str_arr.reverse();

    $.each(str_arr_rev, function (i, item) {
        if ($.inArray(item.toLowerCase(), vowels) > -1) {
            last_vowel_index = i;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (last_vowel_index == -1) {
        $.each(str_arr_rev, function (i, item) {
            if (item.toLowerCase() == "y") {
                last_vowel_index = i;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    if (last_vowel_index > -1)
        str_arr_rev[last_vowel_index] = str_arr_rev[last_vowel_index] + suffix;

    return str_arr_rev.reverse().join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not certain about the second portion of requirement,

> But if two vowel continue with in a word then it should be like :
>
> ```
> Oa = Oaxy and au = auxy -Anup
> ```

Try this pattern

html

```
   <input type="text" value="" /><br />
   <div id="name"></div>
```

js

Edit

original piece did not convert "anupam" to "ANUPAXY", `regex`es may still use adjusting

```
$(function () {
    $("input").on("change", function(e) {       
    $("#name")
        .html(function (index, o) {
        var v = /[aeiou]+.$/gi;
        var o = $(e.target).val();
        var n = v.test(o);
        return (n ? String(o.replace(/[^aeiou]$/gi, "") + "xy").toUpperCase() : o)
    });
   });
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/nB9Qc/

See also

[Is this the shortest javascript regex to find all uppercase consonants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22724661/is-this-the-shortest-javascript-regex-to-find-all-uppercase-consonants)

[How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex)

[Break string after specific word and put remains on new line (Regex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259272/break-string-after-specific-word-and-put-remains-on-new-line-regex)